# Uploading images from other websites to answer a question

Tags: discussion, support, plagiarism, image-upload

I have been warned before regarding the plagiarism and moderators have deleted my two answers in which I used images from other websites to simplify the answer.

What I want to know:

1. Is copying images from other websites subject to copyright? Isn't it allowed in Stack Overflow?
2. If it is, in what kind of situations is it marked as plagiarism?

PS: I have seen similar questions regarding copyright content but my problem is regarding images only.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, not everything on the Internet is free.  It's usually a good idea to see if you can find the license under which the content (text, picture, video, etc.) is licensed.  Most things online have a license, but it's incredibly difficult to determine how you're allowed to use the content.

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. United States copyright law applies to works the moment they are created and applies to artwork. See ["When is my work protected?"](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-general.html#mywork) and ["What does copyright protect?"](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-protect.html#what_protect) (The one has a link to a document regarding agreements with other countries on copyrights.)

Comment: Your profile says you go to school in the UK today.  Do talk to fellow class members about this, they intuitively understand it.  That kind of culture adaption is always quite difficult, takes an easy five years to get the look-and-feel, ten to make it your own.  Don't wave that flag too much to discourage them helping you.

Answer (score 24):

Your posts weren't deleted only because of images. Since you didn't call out which questions you are asking about specifically, I've selected a few that I think you are referring to:

- [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992230/what-is-the-diffrence-between-jit-and-the-execution-engine/55992465#55992465). This was deleted by you after a user posted a comment stating that it wasn't attributed. A few things about this answer you should know. First, it's a bad answer. Really bad. It is an animated picture. You can't Google that, Ctrl+F that or skip to a relevant moment in the video. Don't do this. Second, there is a copyright right on the picture. The user posting a comment is probably correct. This image is not yours and you don't make any sort of reference to the copyright holder. It should be deleted.
- [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896516/how-do-i-edit-an-entry-i-made-to-stackoverflow/55897187#55897187) - Also deleted by you. This is not a question for Stack Overflow. It is a question for *Meta* Stack Overflow and should have been closed not answered. Again, you posted a picture without an explanation. Sure, you have a circle and a arrow, but a few *words* would have been helpful (had this been a good question).
- [Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876848/how-does-visual-studio-know-i-have-made-a-compile-time-mistake-before-i-run-my-c/55877162#55877162) - Again, deleted by you. A very large portion of this (including pictures) is copied from an [external site](https://codeasy.net/lesson/c_sharp_compilation_process). Copying, wholesale, from someone else is not allowed.
- [Post 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477026/how-to-print-an-array-using-oop-writing-a-method-with-no-parameter/55477187#55477187) - Once again, deleted by you. This looks copied from [Course Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55477187/189134)

---

Your posts are not being deleted or flagged because of the images. They are being flagged because you are either posting content that isn't yours without attribution or posting bad content.

I recommend that you read the [guide to referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) in the help center.

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

---

Posts here can reference the work of others, but it should not be a dumping ground for users to copy and paste their work here. Use the work of others to better explain how something works, how to solve a problem or how to do something. Don't grab a page worth of text and pictures and post it here. That doesn't help the person asking questions, that doesn't help someone that Google'd and it doesn't help you.